# How would you detect text based on coordinates in Java?

Tags: java, text, ocr, detect, icr

I'm trying to figure out if there's some kind of library that can recognize characters based on the general locations of coordinate points. It would need to be able to detect various shapes, sizes, scales, variations, etc. In this [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOyqQ.png), it would detect "FFF" (case doesn't matter to me in this instance). If you have any ideas, they are much appreciated! If you think the idea is crazy and not feasible, let me know as well. Thanks!

Comment: You could look into Google's Cloud vision API

Comment: You would google "java OCR", but you would not ask for suggestions like this on Stack Overflow, because they are considered off topic. Please familiarize yourself with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions which will receive good answers.